# Find command on list of directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I have the following directories

```
$ ls
DIR_1
2_DIR_2
DIR_3
```

How would I run the `find` command on certain directories only? For example:

```
$ find "DIR_1/, DIR_3" -type f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the directories in the command line with the same syntax:

```
$ find DIR_1 DIR_3 -type f
```